# problem in the reference on \newtcbtheorem

Tags: ref, newtheorem

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{defn}{Définition}{
colback=green!5,
colframe=green!35!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,}
{defn}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{theo}{Théorème}{
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{prop}{Proposition}{
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{prop}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{lem}{Lemme}{
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{lem}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{coro}{Corollaire}{
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{coro}
\begin{document}
\chapter{CH 1}
\begin{theo}{}{}\label{A}
A
\end{theo}
\section{sec 1}
\begin{prop}{}{}\label{B}
B
\end{prop}
\section{sec 2}
\begin{lem}{}{}\label{C}
C
\end{lem}
\section{sec 3}
\begin{coro}{}{}\label{D}
D
\end{coro}
Théorème ({\color{blue}\ref{A}}), proposition ({\color{blue}\ref{B}}), lemme ({\color{blue}\ref{C}}), corollaire ({\color{blue}\ref{D}}).
\end{document}
```

the result obtained is:

[image]

My problem is, I want the last sentence to be:

" Théorème (1.0.1), proposition (1.1.1), lemme (1.2.1), corollaire (1.3.1)."

An idea please.

Answer (score 2):

Cross references with such theorem-like environments works differently. The label must be in the third argument after `\begin` and the reference must be prefixed by the last item in the definition.

Since you define `theo` with last item `theo`, the references should be like `\ref{theo:A}`.

I don't think there's much to do about this other than using a simpler prefix for everything, here `t`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{defn}{Définition}{
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{t}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{theo}{Théorème}{
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{t}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{prop}{Proposition}{
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{t}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{lem}{Lemme}{
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{t}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{coro}{Corollaire}{
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{t}

\begin{document}
\chapter{CH 1}
\begin{theo}{}{A}
text A
\end{theo}
\section{sec 1}
\begin{prop}{}{B}
text B
\end{prop}
\section{sec 2}
\begin{lem}{}{C}
text C
\end{lem}
\section{sec 3}
\begin{coro}{}{D}
text D
\end{coro}

Théorème (\textcolor{blue}{\ref{t:A}}), 
proposition (\textcolor{blue}{\ref{t:B}}), 
lemme (\textcolor{blue}{\ref{t:C}}), 
corollaire (\textcolor{blue}{\ref{t:D}}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add support for `cleveref`; adjust to suit with the package features.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{defn}{Définition}{
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  label type=defn,
}{t}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{theo}{Théorème}{
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  label type=theo,
}{t}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{prop}{Proposition}{
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  label type=prop,
}{t}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{lem}{Lemme}{
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  label type=lem,
}{t}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{coro}{Corollaire}{
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  label type=coro,
}{t}

\crefname{defn}{définition}{définitions}
\crefname{theo}{théorème}{théorèmes}
\crefname{prop}{proposition}{propositions}
\crefname{coro}{corollaire}{corollaires}
\crefname{lem}{lemme}{lemmes}
\begin{document}
\chapter{CH 1}
\begin{theo}{}{A}
text A
\end{theo}
\section{sec 1}
\begin{prop}{}{B}
text B
\end{prop}
\section{sec 2}
\begin{lem}{}{C}
text C
\end{lem}
\section{sec 3}
\begin{coro}{}{D}
text D
\end{coro}

\Cref{t:A}, \cref{t:B}, \cref{t:C}, \cref{t:D}.

Théorème (\textcolor{blue}{\ref{t:A}}), 
proposition (\textcolor{blue}{\ref{t:B}}), 
lemme (\textcolor{blue}{\ref{t:C}}), 
corollaire (\textcolor{blue}{\ref{t:D}}).

\end{document}
```

[image]